# Parallel revert of virtual machines fails when there are many reverts in progress (webvirtcloud)

Tags: python, libvirt

I'm building project on top of [webvirtcloud](https://github.com/retspen/webvirtcloud) (webvirtcloud uses libvirt-python).

I have several threads. Each of them reverts different virtual machine (VM) via `revertToSnapshot` method. If there are 3 threads then everything goes nice. If there are more then 3 threads then in each thread after like 7 seconds `revertToSnapshot` fails with exception `libvirt: XML-RPC error: Cannot recv data: Connection reset by peer`. It's important to note that despite `revertToSnapshot` method fails, revert process is continued and VM will be reverted.

I tried to create 10 connections to 10 different VMs and consequentially
get status of VMs. My intention was to check if I can create 10 simultaneous connections. It worked normally.

I tried to create new connection in each thread. Implementation looks like:

```
def main():
    ...
    # This is main thread code snippet
    t = threading.Thread(thread_job_funk, (arg1, agr2,))
    t.start()
    ...


def thread_job():
    ...
    connection = wvmInstance(host, login, passwd, conn, vname)
    connection.snapshot_revert("snapshot_name")  
    ...
```

I also tried to create one connection and use it in each thread (yeah it's legal due to libvirt python bindings description). Implementation looks like:

```
vm_host_connection = wvmConnect(ip_addr, login, password, connection_type)

def main():
    ...
    # This is main thread code snippet
    t = threading.Thread(thread_job_funk, (arg1, agr2,))
    t.start()
    ...


def thread_job():
    ...
    global vm_host_connection 
    vir_domain_connection = vm_host_connection .get_instance(instance_name)
    snapshot = vir_domain.snapshotLookupByName(snapshot_name, 0)
    vir_domain.revertToSnapshot(snapshot, 0) 
    ...
```

Then I tried to look at libvirtd (libvirt daemon on host) log for messages connected to keepalive mechanism, nothing was spotted by me. Keepalive logs for period when I reproduced an issue:

```
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx13
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx10
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx11
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx13
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx13
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx11
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0x5585245c7680
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx10
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx10
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx10
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx13
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx7
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx8
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0x55852460af60
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx10
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx9
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx12
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx1, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx2, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx3
info : virKeepAliveTimerInternal:136 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 countToDeath=5 idle=5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive request to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxx13
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=1
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:395 : Got keepalive request from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
debug : virKeepAliveMessage:104 : Sending keepalive response to client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
info : virKeepAliveMessage:107 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_SEND: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:374 : ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5, msg=0xxxxxxxxxxxx4
info : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:391 : RPC_KEEPALIVE_RECEIVED: ka=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 client=0xxxxxxxxxxxx5 prog=xxxxxxxxx5 vers=1 proc=2
debug : virKeepAliveCheckMessage:400 : Got keepalive response from client 0xxxxxxxxxxxx5
```

Then I tried to look for errors and warnings of libvirtd and there were not any errors or warnings while reproducing an issue.

Why method fails when there are more then 3 threads?

Notes:

- Internals of snapshot_revert use revertToSnapshot method of libvirt-python.
- As I understand webvirtcloud is built using libvirt-python

P.S.: Feel free to ask for any additional information.

Comment: As a guess, that sounds like the library you're using may be sharing a single socket to the libvirt daemon. Can you show us some code?

Comment: But I can create 3 connections simultaneously. Yeah, will add code snippet in a few moments.

Answer (score 2):

While the underlying libvirt library [is touted to be thread-safe](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ#Is_libvirt_thread_safe.3F), it seems that parts of `webvirtcloud` [might not be](https://github.com/retspen/webvirtcloud/blob/9aed7c771603dba65739f47508a976fa0ef63216/vrtManager/connection.py#L49):

```
# to-do: may also need some locking to ensure to not connect simultaniously in 2 threads
```

Maybe raise an issue over there? https://github.com/retspen/webvirtcloud/issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) Yeah, I’ll raise an issue soon.

Comment: I realized that we can create one connection and then use it by different threads. In that way we don't meet the situation that is described in `webvirtcloud` comment you referred to.

Answer (score 0):

The libvirt.so library and associated python binding are fully thread safe. You only need to have 1 connection open and can use it concurrently from many threads and it will synchronize as needed.

This error messages and behaviour makes me think that the libvirtd daemon keepalive watchdog is firing (incorrectly) and thus closing the connection to libvirt.

Try running

```
  virt-admin daemon-log-filters 1:keepalive
  virt-admin daemon-log-outputs 1:file:/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log
```

and then reproduce the problem and see if the log messages show a keepalive firing.

If it does, then It is possible that the problem is in fact in the libvirtd daemon.

Comment: Do I need to run these commands on server that is hosting VMs? (I'm newbie with libvirt)

Comment: I looked at logs (attached) and couldn't find anything suspicious.